# Magento 2: Transportbuilder sending empty mails

Tags: magento2, email

I'm trying to use the transportbuilder to send an custom email in my module.
I succeed in sending an email, but the body is always empty.

This is my email_templates.xml (placed in view/frontend/email/)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
        <template id="empty_email_template" label="Empty Template" file="empty.html" type="text" module="Xaiamedia_SyncProducts" area="frontend"/>
    </config>
```

And this is my mail function:

```
    $emailTemplateVariables = array();
    $emailTempVariables['ucdata'] = 'dummy';

    $sendToEmail = 'email@gmail.com';

    $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
    $postObject->setData($emailTempVariables);

    $sender = array('email' => "info@mywebsite.nl", 'name' => 'Mywebsite');

    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('empty_email_template')
    ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
    ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
    ->setFrom($sender)
    ->addTo($sendToEmail)
    ->setReplyTo($sender['email'])            
    ->getTransport();               
    $bla = $transport->sendMessage();
```

And this is my template:

```
    <strong>De volgende producten zijn verwijderd door Lightmakers:</strong>                <br><br>
    <pre>
    {{trans "Ucdata: %ucData" ucData=$data.ucdata}}
    </pre>
```

The email is fully blank (no static template content aswell), but I don't get any error messages while sending.
Is there a way to debug this situation?

Comment: did you debug this?

Comment: Did you find the answer? Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Magento sending empty mail reason is module can not access email template.

Your Sending email code is ok.

You have some directory related issue in putting file .
Follow bellow step.

=> **Step 1 :** Put bellow `email_templates.xml`  in `Xaiamedia_SyncProducts/etc/` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
        <template id="empty_email_template" label="Empty Template" file="empty.html" type="text" module="Xaiamedia_SyncProducts" area="frontend"/>
    </config>
```

**=> Step 2 :** put your defined html `empty.html` to bellow directory

```
Xaiamedia_SyncProducts/view/frontend/email/empty.html
```

All Done!

Answer (score 0):

```
<template id="empty_email_template" label="Empty Template" file="empty.html" type="text" module="Xaiamedia_SyncProducts" area="frontend"/>
```

Change

```
`type="text"` to  `type="html"`
```